# Angular2 - how to trigger an event from the app component to a route

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular2 (haven't had any experience with Angular1) and I am currently working on a small website. What I need to do is pretty straight forward. In the template of the AppComponent, there are two buttons for language selections. I also have a route, let's say /products, where I display a list of products retrieved from a WS (http get via a service). When I press one of the language buttons, I need the products list to be refreshed. I make the http.get request in the ProductsService class, and I subscribe to the observable in the ProductsComponent class. But how do I trigger the get request from the AppComponent, while still receiving the subscription in the ProductsComponent?

Any help would appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you could do two things.

- Add ProductComponent as ViewChild in AppComponent

  ```
  import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
  export class AppComponent{
      @ViewChild(ProductComponent) ProductComponent;
      public reloadProduct(): void {
          this.ProductComponent.reloadProduct();
      }
  }
  ```
- Store Product information in ProductService class in a variable. When you press language button, call the web service and get the new product and store it in the ProductService class variable. Angular will automatically do the change detection in ProductComponent and display the updated product list.

Comment: thank you for your reply, with the first solution this.ProductComponent is undefined when i call reloadProduct(); the second solution doesn't pass the result to the ProductsComponent from the service.

Comment: Did you add ProductComponent in the list of directives in the component definition?

Comment: Are you still getting undefined ?

Comment: Still undefined. Console logging this.ProductComponent in reloadProduct shows undefined

Comment: I have no idea why its undefined. can you post your whole code